# Dinner service out of Los Angeles on Amtrak Southwest Chief

Tags: usa, trains, food-and-drink, amtrak

Is dinner served in the dining car of the Southwest Chief after it leaves Los Angeles going eastbound at 6:15 pm?  I'm asking because usually dinner service starts earlier on Amtrak trains.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick Google search finds numerous reports of dinner being served after leaving LA.

http://trainweb.org/carl/Flagstaff2010/ :

> Hakto told us that our dinner reservation was for 7:45 pm, so we
>   settled into our room.

http://discuss.amtraktrains.com/index.php?/topic/29285-southwest-chief-los-angeles-to-chicago/ :

> Out of LA we rolled right on time to watch the darkening skies of
>   twilight, and we were enjoying dinner somewhere before San Bernardino.
>   Specials were Chicken Enchiladas, Stuffed Shells, and Trout.

http://trainweb.org/carl/TrainsToPlanes/Going.html :

> Where I Dined: Tuesday dinner through Thursday breakfast Amtrak
>   Southwest Chief Diner (meals included in accommodation price): Tuesday
>   Dinner:  8 pm  Trout w/vegetables, roll, salad, and dessert.  A 1/2
>   bottle of Pinot Gris ($13).

[http://www.mattatouille.com/2010/07/southwest-chief-dining-car-from-la.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20121213182808/http://www.mattatouille.com/2010/07/southwest-chief-dining-car-from-la.html) :

> The daily Southwest Chief leaves at 6:55PM [...] Since I wanted to
>   feel a bit like James Bond in Casino Royale (minus the incredibly
>   attractive Eva Green/Vesper Lund), I decided to splurge at the Dining
>   Car, which features classic American dishes in a sensibly appointed
>   rail car.

Comment: Thank you!  I tried searching before posting the question but apparently wasn't using the right phrase.  I plan to reserve a roomette for my trip to Flagstaff, but I wanted to make sure it included dinner as that could represent almost 20% of the accommodation charge.